# Changing from an enum to a linked table

Tags: mysql, enums, linked-tables

We are going to change something that we have an enum to an id of a linked table instead.

How would we go about that?

Our current enum name: `strat`
Our new linked name: `stratid`

What I was thinking was something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE table_name  
SET stratid = (SELECT id FROM link_table WHERE stratname = table_name.strat);
```

I have **not** created the link table yet, right now it is all theory.

Will the above work?
Is there anything I should change in order to transfer from an enum to the linked table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No gotchas for making the update other than that you <del>need</del> want to make triple sure that your `link_table.id`s are populated strictly in the order that `table_name.strat` options are defined.

For example, if `strat` is `enum('FOO', 'BAR')` then in `linked_table` the record with `id == 1` should be the "FOO" record.

After that, you 'd perhaps want to make the `stratid` column `NON NULL`; this is not strictly equivalent to your previous arrangement, but it would probably be closer to what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by `strictly in order`? there will be multiple records using the same id...

Comment: @Neal: Made an edit. I meant that you want (need is too strong) the ids of each value in your linked table to be equal to the integer values of the corresponding enum element -- just an added compatibility measure.

Comment: The enum values are **not** integers.

Comment: @Neal: They are *mapped* to integers, and those are the ones I 'm referring to (see manual page, section starting with *"An enumeration can have a maximum of 65,535 elements."*).

Comment: Have to agree with Neal. The current enum values are strings, so populating a linking table with strings gives no regard to the ids they receive. All the code referring to the enums are based on strings, not ids. So the ids assigned to the strings upon insertion into the new linking  table are arbitrary.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision: I totally agree with you (however, I believe Neal misunderstood my meaning initially). But since they *are* arbitrary, making them match the underlying enum values can only be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create the link table first,
set the stratname as unique,
use an auto increment ID

A lazy solution for insert link_table:

```
insert into link_table
select distinct strat from table_name order by strat;
```

However, I not sure is all the predefined enum is being used.

Also, without knowing size of the enum,
I can't suggest you do a manual insert.

If you look at enum ...

```
enum('...', '...', ...)  <-- is just a comma separated value
```

So, here is the query to get the CSV :-

```
select column_type from information_schema.columns 
where schema_name="table_name" and column_name = "strat";
```

You can combine with an programming language to do the link_table insertion.

Lastly, you UPDATE query is not very optimize, you can switch to use INNER JOIN.
But I assume is one-time job, so be it!